# android.compileSdkVersion is missing while using a custom plugin task

Tags: gradle

I have a task to create javadocs :

```
Task tCreateJavadocs = addTask(project, 'createJavadocs', Javadoc.class)
tCreateJavadocs.configure{
source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
   classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
failOnError false
}
```

Now, I have a custom plugin where I move all my tasks and create a library as a result so I can apply the library to all projects. So, I want to move this task to custom plugin project as well. 
I write the task in custom plugin project like below:

```
Task tCreateJavadocs = addTask(project, 'createJavadocs', Javadoc.class)
tCreateJavadocs.configure{
source = project.android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
   classpath += project.files(project.android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
failOnError false
}
```

When I compile this with an Android Studio project, I get error 'Cause: android.compileSdkVersion is missing'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you try to use stuff that is not yet set.
Either apply you plugin later, after you've set the `compileSdkVersion`, or maybe delay configuration of your task with `afterEvaluate`, so that other configurations are already done, or if possible only delay evaluation of the problematic value with a closure.

Last option is probably the best one. Find out which line is problematic and look whether you can give it a `Closure` instead, as those are usually evaluated lazily.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the answer above, I added these:

```
project.android.compileSdkVersion = 'android-23'
project.android.buildToolsVersion = '23.0.1'
```

and project is building

Comment: Where you added these lines. I am getting the same error in this line (classpath += project.files(project.android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))).

Answer (score 0):

If I write my task definition inside project.afterEvaluate closure, the issue is resolved.